# How to Disable eclipse hierarchy in editor

Tags: eclipse

Well, I have an image of the problem:[image: The problem]

and I want to get rid of the marked section. I have accidently activated it when eclipse was frozen (lagging, my pc is very bad) and the section is (for some reason) taking a LOT of resources. Everything I program is delayed about 1/10th of a second and it really pi**es me off. xd

Thanks for any help, its very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the ***Java Editor Breadcrumb***.

To turn it off there is a button in the toolbar. If you hover over the button, it will show *Toggle Breadcrumb*. Click on it.

See Eclipse Help: [Java Editor Breadcrumb](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-java-editor-breadcrumb.htm)